# Is there a way to differentiate a function containing a sum or a product?

Tags: r

I have the following equation:

[image]

and I'm trying to generate  the analytic derivative .
I know you can use `deriv()` and `D()` for an expression , but I cannot seem to figure out how to actually implement a sum or a product notation into an expression.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is.  You should be able to create a function `foo <- function(x,a,b){ your_formula_written_out}` and enter that as the `expr` in `deriv`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: `D(expression(sum(beta*x)), "beta")` →
Error in D(expression(sum(beta * x)), "beta") :  Function 'sum' is not in the derivatives table

Comment: @BenBolker ahhh, thanks.  Guess the OP may have to write a loop over his summation?

Comment: Worse than that (see my [non-]answer).

Comment: Guess it's time for  Macsyma aka Maxima

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**partial/incomplete answer**

The [Deriv package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=Deriv) offers a more robust (and extensible) alternative to the base R `D` and `deriv` functions, and appears to know about `sum()` already.  `prod()` will be difficult, though (see below).

A very simple example:

```r
library(Deriv)
Deriv(~ sum(b*x), "b")
## sum(x)
```

A slightly more complex answer that sort-of works:

```r
Deriv(~ sum(rep(a, length(x)) + b*x), c("a","b"))
## c(a = sum(rep(x = 1, length(x))), b = sum(x))
```

Note here that `sum(a+b*x)` doesn't work (returns 1) for the derivative with respect to `a`, for reasons described in `?Deriv` (search for "rep(" in the page): the `rep()` is needed to help `Deriv` sort out scalar/vector definitions. It's too bad that it can't simplify `sum(rep(x=1, length(x)))` to `length(x)` but ...

Trying

```r
Deriv( ~ exp(sum(a+b*x))/prod(1+exp(a+b*x)))
```

gives an error

> Could not retrieve body of 'prod()'

You **might** be able to add a rule for products to the derivatives table, but it will be tricky since `prod()` takes a `...` argument. Let's try defining our own function `Prod()` which takes a single argument `x` (I think this is the right generalization of the product rule but didn't think about it too carefully.)

```r
Prod <- function(x) product(x)
drule[["Prod"]] <- alist(for(i in 1:length(x)) { .dx[i]*Prod(x[-i]) })
Deriv(~Prod(beta*x), "x"))
```

Unsurprisingly (to me), this doesn't work: the result is 0 ... (the basic problem is that using `.dx[i]` to denote the derivative of `x[i]` doesn't work in the machinery).

I don't know of a way to solve this in R; if I had this problem (depending on more context, which I don't know), I might see if I could find a framework for *automatic differentiation* (rather than symbolic differentiation). Unfortunately most of the existing tools for autodiff in R use backends in C++ or Julia (e.g. see [here](https://user2021.r-project.org/participation/technical_notes/t154/technote/) (C++ + Rcpp + CppAD), [here](https://github.com/Non-Contradiction/autodiffr) (Julia), the [TMB package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=TMB) (C++/CppAD/user-friendly extensions). There's an ancient pure-R [github project](https://github.com/quantumelixir/radx) `radx` but it looks too incomplete to use ... (FWIW `autodiffr` requires a Julia installation but doesn't actually require you to write any Julia code, AFAICS ...)